# ввод бот telegram на python

Tags: telegram-bot, python-3.9

как мне сделать чтобы бот видел что я пишу и если в моем сообщение написано какое то плохое слово то бот писал бы мне что типа какой я плохой
подскажите пожалуйста
вот код

```
from Token import Token_on_telegram_bot
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from telebot import types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

bot = Bot(token=Token_on_telegram_bot)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет Я телеграм бот!")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["help"])
async def help_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("дарова")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для упрощения задачи попробуйте подключить стороннюю библиотеку типа pyTelegramBotAPI. Это можно сделать с помощью pip:

```
pip install pytelegrambotapi
```

Или из исходников (требуется git):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI.git
$ cd pyTelegramBotAPI
$ python setup.py install
```

Дальше попробуйте повторить операцию, описанную в разделе **Hello, bot!** этой статьи: https://tproger.ru/translations/telegram-bot-create-and-deploy/ На ваше "Привет" бот также поздоровается. Задав условия, можно фильтровать входящие сообщения, такие как маты, и выводить на них соответствующий ответ от бота. Выглядит "фильтр" таким образом:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
   if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
       bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет!')
   else:
       bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Не понимаю, что это значит.')
```